# Converting an array to text without dividers in Google apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I've retrieved a row of sheet values into an array of text values. The array form is [[a, b, c, d, e, f]]. I'd like the final result after processing to be a text value of 'abcdef'.

Here's the code, which doesn't work:

```
function arrayConcatToText() {

//Goal is to have this: [[a, b, c, d, e, f]]
//look like this: 'abcdef'

var testArray=[['a','b','c','d','e','f']];

var testArrayToText=testArray.join('');

Logger.log(testArrayToText);

//Result of code is 'a,b,c,d,e,f' rather than desired 'abcdef'

}
```

I've tried other things, but this seems to be the closest route.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your situation, `var testArray = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']];` is 2 dimensional array. In this case, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
var testArrayToText=testArray.join('');
```

#### To:

```
var testArrayToText = testArray[0].join('');
```

#### Testing:

```js
var testArray = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']];
var testArrayToText = testArray[0].join('');
console.log(testArrayToText);
```

- If `testArray` is like `[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']]`, how about the following modification?

```js
var testArray = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']];
var testArrayToText = testArray.map(e => e.join(''));
console.log(testArrayToText);
```

Comment: Drats! So obvious. Thank you.